# Using vue js with existing application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hello I have existing web app written in django and I want to add some vue js feautures.
I don't want to have all the pain  with webpack, so I can stick to including vue.js as an external script like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

as sugested here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#ad

Also I have on my page this html:

```
<div id="app">
    just an app
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

And the following inline script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    })
</script>
```

But there is no message "Hello vue" on my page. As you can see on the printscreen
So what do I do?
[image]

Comment: Why are you downvoting it? I am doing as described in official tutorial, I have given a link. What's wrong with my desire not using webpack and just to add some vue.js fancy functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution 
it didn't work, cause django used the same braskets as vue.js
something like this `{{variable}}`

So I turned off django braskets:
like this:

```
{% verbatim %}
<div id="app">
    just an app
  {{ message }}
</div>
{% endverbatim %}
```